# javascript function will not return value or object

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Please help trying to get this function to return value back to my main process. currently everything shows in the console however if I return the object its blank or undefined

```
const GetSelectDeviceFromDB = () => {
  db.all("SELECT * FROM device_list", function (err, rows) {
    rows.forEach(function (row) {
      console.log(row.device);
      return row.device;
    });
  });
};

module.exports = { GetSelectDeviceFromDB };
```

OUPUTS:
console.log =.  { device1, device2 } 
return = undefined and if I add the return to the beginning of the sql statement I get {}

Comment: `forEach()` doesn't return anything. Use `map()` to return a list of the result of each function.

Comment: But `db.all()` is asynchronous. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `all()` method is [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) and it is using a callback, you can turn your method into a method like this:

```
const GetSelectDeviceFromDB = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  db.all('SELECT * FROM device_list', (err, rows) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
    const devices = rows.map((row) => row.device);
    resolve(devices);
  });
});
```

It will return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you can call it like this:

`GetSelectDeviceFromDB().then(devices => { ... })`

Answer (score 0):

Returning from `forEach` isn't a good idea, returning from another object's method (`db.all` in you case) isn't either. You need to return exactly in the first scope of the lambda function, somewhere outside of `db.all(...)`. But in this case it's an async method, so you should make your whole function async or a Promise